# cleveref package only print the first reference, the rest are just question marks

Tags: cleveref

I want to cross reference multiple equations at a single place and I found that 
`cleveref` package is what I need. But I find that cleveref can not work properly: it only print the first equation ref correctly.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
   a = b+c
 \end{equation}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq2}
   e = mc^2
 \end{equation}

 \begin{equation}\label{eq3}
    r = d +e
 \end{equation}

 \begin{equation}\label{eq4}
   f = j + m
 \end{equation}

 \begin{equation}\label{eq5}
    s = p +b
 \end{equation}

   See~\cref{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5} for more information.
 \end{document}
```

The above code produces something like this:
[image]

Only one equaiton reference is printed correctly. What is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleveref is sensitive to the space in the label and as a result, you cannot have spaces after the comma.  It is trying to find the reference `' eq2'` as opposed to `'eq2'` (the `'` are there to make the space salient).

Here's the fixed version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  a = b+c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
  e = mc^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
  r = d +e
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
  f = j + m
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq5}
  s = p +b
\end{equation}

See \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5} for more information.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Yes, the space after the comma is the problem.  But it just makes no sense why space after comma is not allowed.